# Apache says a virtual host is configured, but I can't find it

Tags: apache

I have double checked to make sure that no sites are configured by running the following command:

```
[user:ubuntu:/etc/apache2]$ sudo a2dissite
Your choices are: 
Which site(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?
*
ERROR: No site found matching *!
```

However, if I navigate to my IP address, I can see the directory listing for `/var/www/html`.

There's nothing in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` folders, which is where I store all of my configuration files (in `sites-available` at least).

However, I can see that there *is* some configuration file loaded, by running:

```
[user:ubuntu:...tal/public/vphish/campaigns]$ apache2ctl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

I've never had this happen to me before. Any idea where I can trace this and figure out where this configuration file is located? I even did a `grep -Ri "var/www/html" /etc/apache2` and the `DocumentRoot` that is shown there isn't even in any of the files within the `/etc/apache2` directory. It looks like it's a virtualhost, but I can't find it.

Also, my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file includes a custom folder that I added in there, but there's no configuration file in there either.

Comment: Have you reloaded or restarted your Apache server to make sure the cache is clear.

Comment: Restarted and reloaded. Also rebooted server as well.

Comment: 1) If you add a page.html to your /var/www/html do you see it appear in the browser directory listing? 2) Are you sure you are looking at the correct server (correct IP address)?

Comment: 3) Is there anything in your `/var/lib/apache2/` directory that might be useful? Sites that are enabled should show up in `/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin`

Comment: Added a text file and was able to browse to it. I just reinstalled Apache and apparently this must be the default setting? If you disable all of the websites, it's almost like Apache uses the last setting? I know this probably the way it works, but that's how it seems. After reinstalling, I just reproduced the same issue.

Comment: This looks useful to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846647/default-page-still-accessible-after-a2dissite-000-default-conf

Comment: Makes sense. So weird. Thanks so for the link! Glad to have this clarified because my head was SPINNING.